# How to disable logging in NewAer SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have implemented NewAer SDK v. 3.1.3 (https://newaer.com/sdk/ios/) in my app. While running, it produces a lots of messages in the Xcode console (tens of messages per second). I've checked NewAer's documentation (https://newaer.com/docs/apple/) and the help desk (https://getsatisfaction.com/toothtag/) but didn't find the answer.

Any ideas how to disable console logging from this SDK?

Comment: Nope, i've just heard it now. Maybe you better contact the newaer team support for getting the answer of it. @Iraklii